# App inventor problem - This block needs a value block connected to its socket

Tags: app-inventor

I am a total beginner in app inventor and i keep getting this message:
"This block needs a value block connected to its socket" when I try to make a label block write something.

Does anyone know why ?..

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem too. You wrote it 2 years ago, but I just started. Anyway, what you need to do is choose logic from the top and add true to the end, so it will be like this
If you type set label 1.visiable to it gives an error

You need to add set label 1.visiable to true, if the end is sharp, you can double click and open it.

If a picture is added, I will add it below.enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4K84.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxWLL.jpg)